# Mongo $meta textScore not returning in query result

Tags: mongodb

I have the following query:

```
db.OPPORTUNITY.aggregate(
[
    {
        "$match": {
            "$text": { "$search": "my search query" },
            "ACCT_PRIMARY_SALES_TERRITORY": {
                "$in": [...]
            },
            "STAGE_NAME": {
                "$nin": [...]
            },
            "FORECASTCATEGORY": { "$ne": "..." },
            "RECORD_TYPE_VALUE": "...",
            "FISCAL_PERIOD": "Q3-2020"
        }
    },
    { 
        "$sort": { 
            "score": { "$meta": "textScore" } 
         }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$ACCOUNT_NAME",
            "count": { "$addToSet": "$_id" },
            "amount": { "$sum": "$USD_CURRENCY_AMOUNT" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "score": { $meta: "textScore"},
            "title": "$_id",
            "count": { "$size": "$count" },
            "amount": 1,
        }
    }
]
)
```

When I end up calling this query, I get the following response:

`{amount: 12345.0, title: "Company Name", count: 3}`

How do I get the score metadata to also display? I assumed it would when I added score in my `$project`. Is there something with the order or structure of my query that is allowing to return a query response but exclude the `textScore`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage is essentially *"destructive"* in the pipeline in the sense that it *redefines* the properties that are now available in the document. This is also true of a [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) in the same way that the things you do not explicitly include as output from that stage are not emitted.

This includes the [`$meta`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/meta/) information. So if you want it returned, then you need to actually return the value explicitly within the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) instead:

```
{ 
    "$sort": { 
        "score": { "$meta": "textScore" } 
     }
},
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$ACCOUNT_NAME",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 },
        "amount": { "$sum": "$USD_CURRENCY_AMOUNT" },
        "score": { "$first": { "$meta": "textScore" } }   // Use a $first or other appropriate accumulator 
    }
},
{
    "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "score": 1,
        "title": "$_id",
        "count": 1,
        "amount": 1,
    }
}
```

But even as basic reasoning here the result of [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) is just not the same document as returned from the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage of the pipeline as it basically "transforms", so you cannot expect that "meta" information to still be attached. Also note that you are **grouping** by a different property so just like the usage of `$sum` here you also need to use a valid accumulator since these values will come from multiple documents obtained.

So anything in a [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) other than the `_id` **must** have an accumulator action. Be it [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) or [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) or [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) or [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) depending on what you actually need.

Also note that your usage of [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) here was basically redundant since it is not possible for the original document `_id` values of a collection to be anything other than **unique**. So a "distinct count" of the *primary-key* values is essentially just the total count of the grouping, or just `{ "$sum": 1 }`. Not only is that the same result, but it is also not prone to problems should the number of array/set items actually become large enough that the result might breach the 16MB BSON limit.

The main concept you really need to grasp is that each "pipeline stage" can only ever see the output that the previous stage emits. Therefore stages like [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) which only return exactly what you specify and no other values, must actually include the properties you intend to reference at any later stage of the pipeline.

Comment: Thank you. The sort feature doesn't seem to work in terms of sorting by score though. If you don't mind, please include how you can get the top 0-N query results (i.e. return the top 0 or up to N query results and exclude if results are > N)

Comment: @btrballin That is because you are applying a `$sort` before a `$group`. A `$group` will not guarantee ANY order of output, and pretty much as stated it is generally another "destructive" stage. If you want "ordered by scores", then you basically again apply the same principles of doing that **after** you projected your final values. Again, this is the *learning curve* as aggregation pipelines are *sequential* and not the same as expressions in SQL statements.

Comment: Thanks. I added `{"$sort": { "score": -1 }}` after my `$project` and it works!